# Styling or override input text with password mask

Tags: html, css, forms

Let's say I have this

```
Name : <input type="text" name="name" />
```

I want to mask the user input with password sign either like asterix or dot. Is it possible to do this?

Yes, I know I could do  `Password : <input type="password" />` but I want to do with `input type="text"` . Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with `<input type="password" />` ?

Comment: I dont think anything is wrong with type=password, but probably he wanted to use type=tel for mobile devices, therefore looking a way to mask the entry. (wow I just realized that this post is almost 3 years old)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to do this as we have `type="password"` but still if you want to hide the fields which have `type="text"` than you can use this (Only webkit)

```
input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AqwaY/) (Webkit Only)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type to password.

```
Name : <input type="password" name="name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
<input type="password"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use input type="password".use javascript keyup function and make a custom replace function